# Geometry: Name of rectangle with 1-4 rectangular corner cutout(s)

Tags: geometry, polygons

Do rectangles with 1-4 fixed-orientation rectangular corner cutout(s) have proper names?

Two example shapes with 3 and 2 cutouts, respectively:

[image]

I understand that they are [polyrect-like](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Polyrect.html), [simple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_polygon), [concave](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concave_polygon) polygons, but as a mathematical concept I assume the constrain here (rectangle with fixed-orientation rectangular corner cutout(s)) could have a more specific name. For reference, [pentominos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentomino) are a type of similar geometric figures that are named.

If there are separate names for the shapes with 1, 2, 3 or 4 cutouts, then I'm interested in those names.

If these shapes don't have proper names, is there a more succinct way to describe them than “rectangles with fixed-orientation rectangular corner cutout(s)”?

The characteristics of the shape is important for [nesting problems](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/155395/155206).

(Yes, it's a very simple question, but I can't find the answer neither on Google nor Stack Exchange.)

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you interested in this? Why do you believe there should be a name for this figure, in what context is it "special" enough to deserve a name?

Comment: The shapes are extremely basic, e.g. with 1 cutout it's L-shaped, and I just assume such basic shapes must have mathematical names, when e.g. the [truncated icosahedron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncated_icosahedron) has been blessed with a name :-) And proper, succinct naming it is helpful for discussing any [nesting algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nesting_algorithm) (my overarching interest)

Comment: I mean, they're not that basic. You need 3 numbers to describe every cutout.

Comment: These figures do not  have particular names. If you find a paper that studies them the author may have invented names to use in that paper. If you want to study them, invent helpful names.

Comment: @EthanBolker, I rephrased the question into “Do [they] have proper names?”. If the answer is “No”, can you supply that as an answer?

Comment: I doubt there's a name. I'd call them *mutilated rectangles*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no names in the literature for these particular shapes.

You can call them mutilated rectangles (as @GerryMyerson suggests) or name them utah0 (for ordinary rectangles through utah4 - utah1 is the map of Utah. There will be two kinds of utah2.

Comment: I ♡ the suggestion Utah!